# If dicts in python are mutable, why does editing a dict contained in a second dict not change the second dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, immutability, mutable

I'm new to python and am just learning about immutable and mutable objects (I've never came across this before with my limited coding experience in MATLAB and C#).

I wanted to know why, if dicts in python are mutable, does editing a dict contained in a second dict not change the second dict?

Here is an example, where a dict (batman) is added to a dict of superhero names (super_hero_names). When batman is later changed, it isn't reflected in the superhero names dict. This makes sense to me if dicts were immutable like strings, but they are mutable so why is this happening?

```
super_hero_names = {
    'Superman' : 'Clark Kent',
    'Spiderman' : 'Peter Parker'
}

batman = {'Batman' : 'Bruce'}

super_hero_names.update(batman)

batman['Batman'] = 'Bruce Wayne' # (edited)

print(super_hero_names)

# Output: {'Superman': 'Clark Kent', 'Spiderman': 'Peter Parker', 'Batman': 'Bruce'}
```

Comment: "why, if dicts in python are mutable, does editing a dict contained in a second dict not change the second dict?" Because `batman` isn't contained in `super_hero_names`.

Comment: So is that because using dict.update() doesn't reference the batman object, unlike how changing a list that was previously put into (referenced in) a second list also changes the second list?

Comment: `.update()` inserts the new *values* into the dictionary. It doesn't insert *references*.

Comment: Also, the example is somewhat broken because you're assigning a new dictionary to the `batman` variable, not changing the old dictionary, but that doesn't really change the outcome.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I just edited the question to fix that broken part (I think).

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Mutable names

The problem in your code is that strings are immutable: you cannot modify the string `'Bruce'` into `'Bruce Wayne'`. You replace it and the reference is gone. If you use a mutable object as value, you can achieve the desired result:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.name)


super_hero_names = {
    'Superman': Person('Clark Kent'),
    'Spiderman': Person('Peter Parker')
}

bruce = Person('Bruce')
batman = {'Batman': bruce}

super_hero_names.update(batman)

bruce.name = 'Bruce Wayne'

print(super_hero_names)
# {'Superman': 'Clark Kent', 'Spiderman': 'Peter Parker', 'Batman': 'Bruce Wayne'}
```

## Your example in Ruby

Ruby and Python often have a very similar syntax. Ruby strings are mutable, so your code would work in Ruby with very few modifications:

```
super_hero_names = {
    'Superman' => 'Clark Kent',
    'Spiderman' => 'Peter Parker'
}

batman = {'Batman' => 'Bruce'}

super_hero_names.update(batman)

batman['Batman'] << ' Wayne' # Mutates the string, doesn't replace it!

print(super_hero_names)
# {"Superman"=>"Clark Kent", "Spiderman"=>"Peter Parker", "Batman"=>"Bruce Wayne"}
```

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question. I think this was the most direct answer, but the other answers were also pretty great!

Answer (score 1):

You *could* achieve what you want by storing the names in lists, but it makes the code more cluttered and less efficient, due to the extra layer of indirection.

```
super_hero_names = {
    'Superman' : ['Clark Kent'],
    'Spiderman' : ['Peter Parker'],
}

batman = {'Batman' : ['Bruce']}
super_hero_names.update(batman)

batman['Batman'][0] = 'Bruce Wayne'
print(super_hero_names)
```

**output**

```
{'Superman': ['Clark Kent'], 'Spiderman': ['Peter Parker'], 'Batman': ['Bruce Wayne']}
```

We could also do that update using

```
batman['Batman'][0] += ' Wayne'
```

Comment: Indeed. The values need to be mutable. You used a list and I used a custom class, but the principle is the same.

Comment: @EricDuminil Agreed. Your class makes the code a little more verbose for this simple case, but it's clean, and easily extensible for more complex cases.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you create the dictionary `batman`, you are actually creating a dictionary and assigning it to the variable `batman`

I believe what you are trying to do is this:

```
super_hero_names = {
    'Superman' : 'Clark Kent',
    'Spiderman' : 'Peter Parker'}
batman = {'Batman' : 'Bruce'}
super_hero_names.update(batman)
super_hero_names['Batman'] =  'Bruce Wayne'
print(super_hero_names)
```

The output in this case will be:

```
{'Superman': 'Clark Kent', 'Spiderman': 'Peter Parker', 'Batman': 'Bruce Wayne'}
```

Comment: Yes, that does what I want, however, I really wanted to figure out how changing the original dictionary could change the second. Is there another method to combine dictionaries that could do this?

Comment: No. The two dictionaries are never "linked." You could keep assigning a new dictionary to the original dictionary, but after you make the update, python considers its job done.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this explains your question. When you update a dictionary it updates dictionary with the values of another dictionary, It is merging. But when you insert one dictionary into other mutability exists

```
super_hero_names = {
    'Superman' : 'Clark Kent',
    'Spiderman' : 'Peter Parker'
}

batman = {'Batman' : 'Bruce'}

super_hero_names['new'] = batman

print(super_hero_names)

batman['Batman'] = 'Bruce Wayne'

print(super_hero_names)

batman = {'Batman' : 'Bruce Wayne'}

print(super_hero_names)
```

## Output

```
{'Spiderman': 'Peter Parker', 'new': {'Batman': 'Bruce'}, 'Superman': 'Clark Kent'}
{'Spiderman': 'Peter Parker', 'new': {'Batman': 'Bruce Wayne'}, 'Superman': 'Clark Kent'}
{'Spiderman': 'Peter Parker', 'new': {'Batman': 'Bruce Wayne'}, 'Superman': 'Clark Kent'}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get that explanation. So, is there no way for mutability to exist by merging dictionaries?

Comment: No, Merging is not mutable

Comment: If you understood, close this question by accepting answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `update()` behaves like this:

```
for key, value in batman.items():
    super_hero_names[key] = value
```

Here, `super_hero_names.update(batman)` first checks whether `super_hero_names` has 'Batman' key. If exist, it overwrite (or update) the value. If not, it create 'Batman' and just *assign* the value to the key.

---

Added:

Here is a sample code. Instead of using dictionary as a data container, I used list to hold multiple superman dictionaries. As you said, dictionary is mutable, so update method modifies the contents in the list of `super_hero_names`.

```
superman = {'Superman' : 'Clark Kent'}
spiderman = {'Spiderman' : 'Peter Parker'}

super_hero_names = [
    superman,
    spiderman
]

batman = {'Batman' : 'Bruce'}
super_hero_names.append(batman)
print(super_hero_names)
# [{'Superman': 'Clark Kent'}, {'Spiderman': 'Peter Parker'}, {'Batman': 'Bruce'}]

batman.update({'Batman': 'test'})

print(super_hero_names)
# [{'Superman': 'Clark Kent'}, {'Spiderman': 'Peter Parker'}, {'Batman': 'test'}]
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! That clears up how `update()` works in this case, so is there another way in which I could combine these two dictionaries for mutability to exist (other than putting a dictionary in a dictionary)?

Comment: Updated answer. How about this one?

Comment: But this makes it impossible to key-search in `super_hero_names`. If you want do it, I recommend to refer @Eric Duminil's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer! I chose @Eric Duminil's answer, as it seemed that is was the most direct and useful, but yours also answers my question. I also found the explanation of `update()` quite informative.